# Giant Defy 2018 front brake cable routing problem

Tags: brakes, cable, giant, cable-routing

[image]I have a feeling that there is something very obvious I am missing.

Just got my Giant Defy Advanced 2. Fitted the front wheel and found the way the front brake cable is routed means it is in the inside of the fork and rubs against the tyre. I cannot see any more points where I can attach the cable to the fork to obtain more clearance.

It looks as if the fork is on the right way round.

[image: cables and fork]

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What about handlebars and the way the cable is routed there? Add another picture of the cockpit, it might help. If nothing, the cable hose might need to be cut shorter

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick [google image search on 'Giant Defy 2018'](https://www.google.com/search?q=Giant%20Defy%202018&tbm=isch), found a couple of pics from the left hand side of the bike.

The front brake cable is supposed to run *outside* then down the back of the left fork leg.

As you are assembling this yourself I guess you did not purchase at a bike store. If you did though, take it back and have them fix the issue and check for other problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yeah, was thinking the same. Was ordered online had to do minor assembly (pedals,seat,front wheel) so I guess they routed the cable wrong. I'll drop into a local shop and ask them to disconnect the cable and reconnect outside the fork (not confident about doing it myself, got visions of brake fluid flying everywhere!).

Comment: Easier to detach the caliper and unwind the cable around the fork leg, making sure cable not kinked. You want to be confident about re-installing the caliper correctly though (aligned with rotor, bolts torqued to spec.)

Comment: +1 on just disconnecting the caliper. Following a video tutorial to get it aligned should give perfect results. Just make sure you have access to a torque limiting tool.

Comment: @Ade You can do this - needs exactly one tool, a hex or torx driver to fit the caliper mounts.  Take the wheel out while moving caliper, and avoid touching the rotor.  Also don't squeeze the brake lever while the rotor is out.

Comment: Thanks to you all for the advice. I work for a car dealership and a bunch of guys here have bikes and one of them works on bikes quite a lot. He fixed it in 5 mins doing what you said about disconnecting the caliper, adjusted the brake too, nice smooth spinning wheel now, better than before! Thanks again.